# Error 401 when restart springboot application

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have an application run on port 8082, config to working with spring security and keycloak (keycloak-springboot-2-adapter, spring-boot-starter-security, ..) And run the standalone keycloak server on port 8080.

Everything working well, but I meet an issue like that:

When I call a web-view by chrome to application 8082 without logging before, the request will be direct to login-page by keycloak manage (I'm using credentials), after I login success and go to the web-view have a button generate random string on the screen.

Stop here and then I restart the application on 8082 (server keycloak still running on 8080). when the application restarts success, I try to click on the button to make an AJAX request to application (api generate random string), but ajax response an error 401 Unauthorized and I don't see any error or exception on both application or keycloak server, just show on console of chrome like that

[image]

If I reload the page and click button again or open link error in console with new tab will return the random string I want. The important thing is I still logging and call another webview success.

If instead restart application 8082 I restart keycloak server and do everything as above again so the button still working well

[image]

I hope you can help me to find out the problem. Sorry for my English if you feel hard to understand my question because english isn't my native language.
Thank you very much for reading!

Comment: Spring security doesn't log much by default to avoid leakage of sensitive information. You can start by adding the property `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` or the JVM argument `-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`

Comment: Great advice. thanks for it @ChristopherSchneider